# A Genetic linkage problem

Tags: genetics, homework, recombination, genetic-linkage

I have recently switched from electronics to computational biology. So having some hard time with my homeworks. Can someone guide me on this problem?

> Consider 6 genes A,  B, C, D, E, F, G. Some recombination rates are
>   given between these genes AB = 0.2, BC = 0.1, AC = 0.25, AD = 0.5, BD
>   = 0.5, DE = .1, AE = 0.5 ,EF = 0.1 ,DF = 0.15.
>
> a) Find the number of linkage groups? b) Construct possible genetic
>   map showing relative positions of these genes?

Comment: http://hos.ufl.edu/sites/default/files/courses/pmb5056/2012_16_Linkage%20paper%20to%20post.pdf

Comment: Please show the efforts that you put into solving the question.

Comment: @TheLastWord : OK I did it alone. (ABC and DEF in different chromosomes, certainly distance matters)